# Check for Internet Without Using ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE

Tags: android, networking, permissions, connectivity

In Android, is there any way to check whether a device is currently "online" or not ... but WITHOUT requiring ANY permissions?

For example, could I query some other service as to whether IT has internet, like some google service... or some other attribute somewhere that implies connectivity is available?

The reason I ask is that I have an app that requires ZERO permissions and I consider that quite rare and a good thing and I want to keep it that way.

PS - I do know of one way to do this:

Create a TextToSpeech instance that uses the Google engine and try to make it speak in a language that you don't have installed.  If it claims the language is available, allows you to send a speak command, and claims to have completed the task successfully, and yet nothing happens, then there is no internet.

Ironically however, this is precisely what I am trying to avoid, so I need to check for internet before attempting such things... since unfortunately google text to speech doesn't function reliably when internet is disconnected.